# Find subset of functions that satisfy an inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have an unknown function $w=w(x,y)$. I also have another function $N(a,b)$ which is defined by:

\begin{equation}
N(a,b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(x,ax+b) dx
\end{equation}

Where $a$ and $b$ are variables that are independent of $x$. I'm seeking a subset of all the possible functions $w$ that satisfy the following inequality for all $a$ and $b$.

\begin{equation}
0 \leq N(a,b) \leq 1
\end{equation}

In case this problem is too hard, a simplified version of the problem is to find all the functions $w$ that satisfy

\begin{equation}
N(a,b) = 0 \\
\text{OR} \\
N(a,b) = 1
\end{equation}

----------------------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------
To make the problem more specific, assume $w(x,y) = 0$ outside the unit circle ($x^2+y^2>1$). Also assume it's bounded between $-c \leq w(x,y) \leq c$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This is too unspecific, for instance $w=0$ is an example.

Comment: Hi thanks! I agree $w(x,y)=0$ is one possible function that works. Is there a way to characterize all of the functions that work? May I ask how I can I make this more specific - what would you need?

Comment: @daw I've added more specific details to the problem. Is this better?